# Forcing a redraw of the presentation layers of a paused animation

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation

I have a CALayer hierarchy containing a number of animated sub layers. The animations are always attached, however they may be paused at any moment (by setting the speed of the root layer) so that the user can scrub through the animation.

I also have a pinch gesture attached that allows me to zoom into the layer. This generally works perfectly. However, the CALayers that are drawn by hand (via drawInContext:) become pixelated when zoomed.

At the end of the gesture I ensure that I update the content scale of these layers correctly:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

...

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    for (CALayer *layer in _layers) {
        layer.contentsScale = _scale;
    }
}

[CATransaction commit];
```

However, this has no effect **until** the animation moves to the next frame (the user scrubs through the animation).

The problem, then, is that the *presentation* layers of the animation aren't being redrawn. I've tried to change their contentsScale, but the property is read-only on a presentation layer.

Curiously, the CAShapeLayers in the hierarchy are all being re-rendered perfectly.

How can I force a redraw of my paused animation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it's impossible to force the redraw of a paused animation's presentation layers.

I have however worked around the issues by removing the layer and recreating them when the user ends the zoom gesture.